# Write to pdf and print in windows forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf

I am developing a Bill Management System in windows form application using c#.
In orders form I have to generate a Invoice in pdf, save pdf and trigger print.
There are two buttons GenerateBill and GenerateBill&Print.When I click on GenerateBill&Print Order details should save in database and Print pdf.I need code to create pdf in windows forms.

Comment: Are you going to ask a question?

Comment: Nice, so? At least start by posting an [MCVE]. SO is not a code generation site.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Unfortunately this question, as it stands, is off-topic, as you haven't asked a clear question. It sounds more like project requirements, and this isn't a site to solicit code-writing.

Comment: Good luck with your project anyway

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace Full_Profile1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //This is the absolute path to the PDF that we will create
            string outputFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Sample.pdf");

            //Create a standard .Net FileStream for the file, setting various flags
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                //Create a new PDF document setting the size to A4
                using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4))
                {
                    //Bind the PDF document to the FileStream using an iTextSharp PdfWriter
                    using (PdfWriter w = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs))
                    {
                        //Open the document for writing
                        doc.Open();

                        //Create a table with two columns
                        PdfPTable t = new PdfPTable(2);

                        //Borders are drawn by the individual cells, not the table itself.
                        //Tell the default cell that we do not want a border drawn
                        t.DefaultCell.Border = 0;

                        //Add four cells. Cells are added starting at the top left of the table working left to right first, then down
                        t.AddCell("R1C1");
                        t.AddCell("R1C2");
                        t.AddCell("R2C1");
                        t.AddCell("R2C2");

                        //Add the table to our document
                        doc.Add(t);

                        //Close our document
                        doc.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we get output of pdf as the following image format http://i.stack.imgur.com/MmIjY.jpg